# How can I do an action on a given condition?

Tags: f#

I am trying to port a `doIf` function from C# to F#.

here is the C# code:

```cs
static void DoIf(bool c, Action f)
{
    if (c) {
        f();
    }
}
```

Here is my guess:

```ml
let doIf (c: bool) (f: unit -> unit) :unit = 
    if c
    then f ()
    else ???
```

And if I write `doIf true (fun _ -> printfn "hello")`, it would print *hello*.

but I am not sure what should i do with `else` to satisfy the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the answer provided by @aloisdg is as such correct, you don't actually need to explicitly return `unit` if `c = false`. Also, the type annotations aren't needed. I would go with

```
let doIf c f = if c then f()
```

Now the question I would ask myself is whether I actually need the function. In your example, for instance, the number of characters without the `doIf` function is actually less than with and I personally think it reads more easily as well

```
doIf true (fun _ -> printfn "hello")
if true then printfn "hello"
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `()`:

```fs
let doIf (c: bool) (f: unit -> unit) :unit = 
    if c
    then f ()
    else ()

doIf true (fun _ -> printfn "hello")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYwxDsMwDAP3vILIFA/5gIF2zysK1JUQA4IUOPL7XUdcyBt4fO/FGo0h5PjZwdhKxtdMEjbO6Fod@zs6IQe@sGCmMkoMP0kxjymI5KZnL2Hz1idxV3wezdWqOivWk0RsTWP8AQ)

Comment: Whenever the result of an `if` expression is of type `unit`, the `else` branch is optional, and can be omitted: `let doIf c f = if c then f ()`